# Setting up Homestead Laravel environment

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm currently following along with a Laracast video on setting up Homestead 2.0, but when I try the command `~/.homestead $ homestead up` I get this:

```
/home/darren/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:92:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/darren/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/darren/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:92:in `block in configure'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:321:in `provision'
    from /home/darren/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:90:in `configure'
    from /home/darren/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:706:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:706:in `vagrantfile'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:452:in `host'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:179:in `block in action_runner'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:439:in `hook'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:688:in `unload'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post your `Homestead.yaml` file? that'll help with the debugging. The install process shouldn't have changed much since 2.0, but you can run `vagrant up` (from the same folder that contains the `Vagrantfile`) instead of `homestead up`

Comment: ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/tester/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's telling you that `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/darren/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` your SSH key as specified in your `Homestead.yaml` is missing. You may need to generate these keys if it's the first time using SSH on this machine.

Comment: i just generated a key and saved it as id_rsa.pub, run the "homestead up" command and get the same message

Comment: darren@darren-desktop:~/.ssh/id_rsa$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "darren@homestead"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/darren/.ssh/id_rsa): id_rsa 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:zXv0CPW7ni94LCytSKOyGHHE7+QPUelq3U55jAHH9O8 darren@homestead